# boost lambda versus phoenix

Tags: c++, boost-lambda, boost-phoenix

I recently started looking at boost phoenix, as replacement for lambda.
Is phoenix a full replacement for lambda, or is there some lambda functionality which is not provided by phoenix?  is phoenix mature? Are there any gotcha I should know about?

my primary interest are operator composition, control statements and casts are less so

Thanks

Comment: I recently started looking at apples, as a replacement for oranges. Are apples a full replacement for oranges? Are apples mature? Are there any gotcha I should know about?

Comment: @Billy I thought fruit comparison was reserved for intrinsically different concept.  Lambda and phoenix are not so as far as I can tell

Answer (score 10, accepted):

[This post](http://lists.boost.org/boost-users/2008/06/37646.php) answers all your questions. Phoenix is very mature. Phoenix and lambda will be merged. It will be the base for future lambda implementations.