# C++ delegate creation with boost

Tags: c++, boost

I asked a similar question here [C++ delegate creation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5237542/c-delegate-creation) but I need to do this with a new restriction. I'll quickly restate the question

I was wondering if theres a way to mimic this delegate behaviour (from C#) in C++

```
new ModifyTargetingStatus("Reversal", "Reverses physical attacks back at the user", -1, new List<CALL_CONDITION>(){CALL_CONDITION.Targetted}, attemptChange: delegate(CharacterMove move, BattleCharacter[] users, ref BattleCharacter[] targets, BattleCharacter holder, BattleField field)
                {
                    if (targets != null && targets.Length == 1 && targets[0] == holder &&
                        (move.MoveClass == MOVE_CLASS.MC_BASIC_ATTACK ||
                        move.MoveClass == MOVE_CLASS.MC_STACKED_ATTACK) &&
                        !move.MoveFlags.Contains(MOVE_FLAG.MF_UNREFLECTABLE))
                    {
                        targets = users;
                        move.Reflected = true;
                        return true;
                    }
                    return false;
                })
```

I need to be able to do this without using C++0x as I'm stuck on a version of gcc the doesnt support C++0x lambdas. I have the boost library available but I'm jut getting into it so I can't figure out how to do this specifically.

Thanks in advance for the help

Answer (score 0):

Either library should work for creating unnamed functions.

- [Boost Phoenix](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_46_0/libs/spirit/phoenix/doc/html/index.html)
- [Boost.Lambda](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_46_1/doc/html/lambda.html)

See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2852775/boost-lambda-versus-phoenix) too, note that the two libraries will be merged some day.

Answer (score 0):

`boost::bind` is the usual solution to this problem. Refer to their documentation for details.